# Find Object Using id and activatedroute

Tags: angular

I am using the find function to get access to an object by using its id field. I successfully get the id value from the activated route. This is the code to retrieve the object with a defined id. I get undefined as a response.

```
export class StoryDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  story: IStory;
  constructor(private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
  stories: IStory[] = require('../stories.json');
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.story = this.loadStoryByFind(this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    console.log('detail story is ', this.story);
  }

  loadStoryByFind(id) {
    console.log('the stories ', this.stories);
    console.log(' this.stories.find(x => x.id === id: ',  this.stories.find(x => x.id === id));
    return this.stories.find(x => x.id === id);
  }

}
```

This is what the console window displays:

```
story-details.component.ts:20 the stories  (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, date: "June 21, 2020", author: "Da", pictureUrl: "pic1", title: "Scorching", …}
1:{id: 2, date: "June 21, 2020", author: "Da", pictureUrl: "pic2", title: "Closest Thing To A Saint", …}
2: {id: 3, date: "June 21, 2020", author: "Da", pictureUrl: "pic3", title: "Scorching", …}
3: {id: 4, date: "June 21, 2020", author: "Da", pictureUrl: "pic4", title: "Scorching", …}length: 4__proto__: Array(0)

story-details.component.ts:21  this.stories.find(x => x.id === id:  undefined

story-details.component.ts:16 detail story is  undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the id to a number first, what you get from url has always a type of string, and you are comparing a string to a number which is false. try:

```
this.story = this.loadStoryByFind(+this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
```

**+this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') is a number
this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') is a string**